rewrite-maven-plugin - Resolving Poms takes a long time trying to resolve blocked repositories
When I am trying to use the rewrite-maven-plugin in my project (see https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/rewrite-maven-plugin)
When I run the plugin I get a big hang while it tries to resolve a bunch of repositories that are in my list but I don't even have access to over firewall.
So it sits there and times out for several minutes on those before running.
[INFO] --- rewrite-maven-plugin:5.42.0:run (default-cli) @ nicksClient ---
[INFO] Using active recipe(s) [org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot2.SpringBoot2JUnit4to5Migration, org.openrewrite.java.testing.cleanup.TestsShouldNotBePublic]
[INFO] Using active styles(s) []
[INFO] Validating active recipes...
[INFO] Project [nicksClient] Resolving Poms...
[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository http://some.nexushost/content/repositories/releases/ due to: Connect timed out
[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository http://some.nexushost/content/repositories/thirdparty/ due to: Connect timed out
...

Can I specify repositories to exclude?

Do you use a repository manager internally? If so you should correctly set your mirrorOf Entry in your settings.xml file (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

First thing I checked. My settings.xml has the correct maven repositories. I just don't have access to many of them.

I think they are legit in the settings.xml, I just don't happen to have access to many of them from my dev workstation.
is there some way to tell it "don't use these repos x, y, z"

Perhaps it helps you to configure a <timeout> per inaccessible server, as per https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html#connection-timeouts
Support for parsing <timeout> was added in https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/pull/4302
Do note that we do not support per-HTTP method <connectionTimeout>(!).
